# configuring curl extension for php in windows

Tags: php, curl, xampp

I am using the Xampp server with php5 . I have been trying to get the curl extension working. But, unable to do it. I uncommented the php_curl.dll line in php.ini. I dont see curl enabled in phpinfo() . I also copied the ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll files to both syswow64 and system32 directories. Do i have to install anything on the server? Has anyone used xampp server before with curl ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I did not used `XAMPP` but couple of times I've faced problems with `WAMP` extensions on Windows.

Almost always reason was one of the following:

1. There aren't required file in `/ext` directory,
2. Extension line in `php.ini` is commented,
3. I forgot to restart server.

Also, this looks interesting (from link #1 below):

> There’s a straight-forward XAMPP FAQ
>   Entry about their **php.ini** stucture.
>   For those looking for the easy fix,
>   ignore everything but the
>   **/apache/bin/php.ini** file. That’s the
>   **only one** that counts, regardless of
>   which PHP version you’re currently
>   using.
>
> What about all the .dll files you
>   need? Well, you don’t need them.
>   **Everything you need to run CURL on a
>   XAMPP install is included in the
>   download.** Stop downloading extra crap
>   and sticking it all over your system.
>   XAMPP knows what it needs, where it’s
>   at, and how to use it. End of story.

If above steps doesn't help, read following articles (and comments):

- [Using CURL in XAMPP](http://chrismeller.com/2007/04/using-curl-in-xampp)
- [Enable CURL with XAMPP on Windows XP](http://www.tildemark.com/programming/php/enable-curl-with-xampp-on-windows-xp.html)
- [Enable Curl on Xampp](http://jakebohall.com/enable-curl-on-xampp/04/2009)
- [Getting cURL to Work in XAMPP](http://gabrieljones.com/getting-curl-to-work-in-xampp/)

**Be aware of multiple php.ini files in XAMPP. Be sure that you have edited right one.**

P.S. I've just tried to enable cURL in `Wamp/XP`. I've removed leading semicolon `;` from line `;extension=php_curl.dll` and restarted server. Now I can see `cURL support: enabled` in `phpinfo()` page. I guess that's easy in `XAMPP` too.